# Getting data from service on android

Tags: android, performance, service, web

I have a service which provides new images every 5 minutes. I'd like to know how could be the images loaded quickly on android. I was thinking about making a website with images, or an android application - what would be better?

Answer (score 0):

you can use handlers to update your UI thread once your service downloads the image... if your downloading higher resolution images its better to decode it [Efficiently loading Bitmap..](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)